# Rails. How do I extend Authlogc with roles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Authlogic for my user authentication, and would like yo add roles to my users - Need security check from model's and controller's

```
current_user.has_role?('admin') etc
```

There is a lot of role based plugins out there, but I not sure which when to use with Authlogic. Does anyone what works best with Authlogic? (if any..)

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [acl9](http://github.com/be9/acl9/tree/master) plugin. It's a really powerful solution and the author himself suggests Authlogic as underlying Authentication system.

> Acl9 is a authorization solution, so
>   you will need to implement
>   authentication by other means. I
>   recommend Authlogic for that purpose,
>   as it’s simple, clean and at the same
>   time very configurable.

Comment: Thnak you. Authlogic and acl9 it is.